# asp.net by pass RequiredFieldValidator validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have two buttons on my page and I want to trigger validator for only one of them not both.

- first button is in masterpage.
- second one in the page.

I do not want the first button trigger `RequiredFieldValidator` I set `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` button it does not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Validation Groups](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2004/10/24/246945.aspx) allows to apply the validations for a group of controls. It works especially when there are multiple buttons on a page and if one button should trigger validations for set of controls and other button for another set. It can be achieved by setting validationgroup property to some string value on the validator controls along with button control.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Right, but in this case term "validation groups" is itself a answer. I didn't know how to apply this, since there is no markup provided in OP too.